# How to generate a GUID id column in Spark that is of integer type

Tags: apache-spark, uuid, guid, spark-graphx

I know I can do `UUID.randomUUID.toString` to attach an id to each row in my `Dataset` but I need this id to be a Long since I want to use GraphX. How do I do that in Spark? I know Spark has `monotonically_increasing_id()` but that is only for the DataFrame API - what about for Datasets?

Comment: You should still be able to use `monotonically_increasing_id()`. Sure, you will get a dataframe back but does that matter? Dataframes and datasets can usually be used interchangeably.. If it does matter, can you give some more information about this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by dropping into dataframes:

```
case class Row(id: Long, name: String .....)

val ds: Dataset[Row] = ....

val ds2 = ds.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id()).as[Row]
```